# "Have you ever drunk XYZ?"

Tags: verbs

I am not a native English speaker. Suppose I wish to ask an audience whether they have ever had some particular drink (alcoholic)? How am I supposed to ask it?

> Have any of you drunk Carlsberg Beer?

Is the above question grammatically correct? If not, can anybody correct me? How do I change the question when I'm inquiring about a non-alcoholic beverage, such as tea or juice?

Answer (score 8):

You can use "have ... drunk" with any beverage.

> We have drunk Carlsberg on many occasions.
>
> We have drunk tea on many occasions.

You may be confusing "drunk" (past participle of *drink*) with "drunk" (adj. meaning intoxicated). If you think your audience may be prone to the same confusion, you might consider using "tried" instead of "drunk":

> Have any of you ever tried ginseng tea?

Comment: Note that among native speakers there would be no such confusion.

Comment: Well, I'm not native... Although it does not confuse me, the sentence does seem a little strange to us.